# How to define number of images in Qt image's carousel?

Tags: qt, qml, carousel

Well, i saw a Qt Quick Image's Carousel Example in h[ttp://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Qt_Quick_Carousel](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Qt_Quick_Carousel). I adapted for my specific situation and it worked!

Ok, but i'm with problems still. I want to show just 4 images each time, but i didn't see something about this. I'm reading also a QML documentation in http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-tutorial.html...

Do someone know how can i to show just 4 images each time in the that example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pathItemCount`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qml-pathview.html#pathItemCount-prop) property from `PathView` will help you.

Comment: Hey @GooRoo it worked! Thanks... But the PathView handles my Carousel of  strange way, but's ok! I will search some solution, but for this problem worked very well...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, now the carousel shows just 5 images for each time, in a total of 10 images. Ok! But it handles of strange mode, because i'm using a Ellipse path, so the current image stays in the middle and others images stay around, the problem is using "pathItemCount: 5" when i rotate my carousel the image than is showed as the next image and would be the main image now, is changed to another image. Sorry, my english is not so good, so maybe had confused.

But, in resume, my next image than would be the main image, is changed when i rotate the carousel so i don't know really what is the next image.

Comment: Well, i understood what's happen. In fact, using "pathItemCount: 5" the PathView shows just the 5 next items and i would like than it shows the current item, 2 next and 2 before. Do you know how i do this? I'm searching about this... Thanks!