# How to keep visible current, next and before item in PathView QML?

Tags: qt, qml, carousel

well i implemented a image carousel using QML with PathView seeing some examples. I had a doubt about how to define the number of items than i wanted visible and i got my answer here [My answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063737/how-to-define-number-of-images-in-qt-images-carousel/9129964?iemail=1#9129964).

Right now, i'm using pathItemCount property, but i have another problem. I saw than when i define pathItemCount property the QML PathView shows just next items, but as i using that component like a image carousel, i need to show next and previous items of the current item.

Someone know how i do it?

Sorry, i'm really newbie in QML, searching somethings about this but no success until now.

Thanks a lot and sorry my english.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set these properties in your `PathView`:

```
PathView {
    // ...
    preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5
    preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5

    pathItemCount: 5
    // ...
}
```

You can read about it [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-pathview.html#preferredHighlightBegin-prop)